# Eclipse Shortcut to Split Long Strings

Tags: eclipse, editor, keyboard-shortcuts

I swear I've seen someone do this, but I can't find it in the various lists of shortcuts.

Given:

```
String s = "A very long ............................ String";
```

Is there an Eclipse shortcut to turn it into:

```
String s = "A very long ............................ " 
    + "String";
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yup - just hit return when your cursor is in the middle of the string.

Admittedly that puts the + at the end of the first line instead of the start of the second, which is irritating if your style guide demands the latter, but if you're not fussy it's great :)

Comment: I wonder if there's a configuration setting somewhere to change the formatting?

Comment: RE: the issue of putting the `+` at the end of the first line...even though the Eclipse formatter won't split the string for you, it will correct the positioning of the `+` once you've finished splitting. After you've split up the string as desired, highlight the desired lines, and do right-click > source > format (Ctrl-Shift-F on Windows).

Answer (score 1):

All the formatting templates in Eclipse will put the plus on the next row (which *I* find really annoying), so you can simply apply the code formatter and the plus will end up on the next row.

Comment: Hmm... that's not my experience. Will have to try again. Given that our coding conventions say to have the + on the next line (which makes a fair amount of sense, IMO) it would be helpful if you're right...

Comment: Just tried it. With my settings the + ends up on the next line after a ctrl+SHIFT-F

Answer (score 0):

There may be a Quick Fix (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>) for this as well.

I was amazed in 3.4 to discover that there are Quick Fixes to transform +-based string concats into uses of `StringBuilder` or `MessageFormat`. Brilliant!

Answer (score 0):

Also you can format code using regular expression. Select expression, press Ctrl+F and use:

Find: `"\s*?\+\s*?\R(\s*?)"`

Replace with: `"\R$1\+ "`

☑ Regular expressions