# Codestyle / formatter to automatically split/wrap strings in Eclipse when surpassing a certain length

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, checkstyle, formatter

I know we have [this question from 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257251/eclipse-shortcut-to-split-long-strings) and [this question from 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9665560/how-to-force-eclipse-wrap-that-line), both stating we can just hit enter in a long String, and it will automatically put a `"newline indent + "` in between. But since we are four years further, I was wondering if there are any new features / setting that would allow this. (**So yes, this is technically a duplicate, but since it's been four years ago since the last question regarding this I decided to bring it up again.**)

Currently I have Strings in my code (*duh*). For example like this:

```
throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
    "Some random text with a length like" + " this, but also not very long");
```

or this:

```
String test =
    "Another text, this time a bit longer so we should split it" + " after it has surpassed a certain"
    + " length");
```

I was in the process of manually removing all `" + "` on single lines because it just looks uggly, and then had hoped I could just save the file and the Checkstyle / formatter would automatically reapply the `" + "`, but this time on the proper places (for example at 120 line-length).

This would then result in the following:

```
throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
    "Some random text with a length like this, but also not very long");
```

or this:

```
String test =
    "Another text, this time a bit longer so we should split it after it has surpassed"
        + " a certain length");
```

Unfortunately, there appears to be no codestyle formatting setting to allow this behavior as far as I can see. Is there anything added in the past four years that does allow String wraps in Eclipse after surpassing a certain length?