# Wrapping line strings in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm using Luna and trying to get Eclipse to automatically wrap this long string.  I tried changing settings in the Formatter Profile-Line Wrapping-Expressions section without any luck.

```
if (condition!= true) {
    throw new RuntimeException(
            "asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf  asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf  asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf  asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf  asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf  asdf.");
}
```

Comment: You can interrupt the long String explicitly `"asdf asdf asdf" + "asdf asdf asdf"`. That would allow Eclipse to wrap the long text on multiple lines. Since this is effectively changing your code (and thereby affecting its performance) you don't want to let Eclipse do that automatically, do you?

Comment: @Carsten, I thought there was an option to achieve this automatically but I guess I was wrong.

Comment: Unfortunately I know of nothing besides the following answer, to make this easier: http://stackoverflow.com/a/257252/5127499